# pointer in c program

Tags: c, pointers

program in c language

```
void main()      
{
 char *a,*b;    
 a[0]='s';    
 a[1]='a';    
 a[2]='n';    
 a[3]='j';    
 a[4]='i';   
 a[5]='t';   
 printf("length of a %d/n", strlen(a));  
 b[0]='s';  
 b[1]='a';   
 b[2]='n';   
 b[3]='j';   
 b[4]='i';  
 b[5]='t';       
 b[6]='g';      
 printf("length of b %d\n", strlen(b));  
}
```

here the output is :

```
length of a 6    
length of b 12
```

Why and please explain it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder what program on your computer got it's data messed up after that.

Comment: The return type of `main` is `int` not `void` for compliant programs.

Comment: but why the output of veriable 'a' shows correct ? where as 'b' shows wrong for '\0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning to pointer (which contains garbage) without allocating memory. What you are noticing is [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Also `main` should return an `int`. Also it does not make sense to try and find the length of an array of chars which are not `nul` terminated.

This is how you can go about:

[Sample code](http://ideone.com/rhxzJn)

Comment: The assignment *does* happen for me but to a garbage value.

Comment: A garbage value isn't *assigned* to the pointer on initialization. The pointer's value is indeterminate until assigned to.

Comment: @Acme Assigning to the pointer would be e.g. `a = "hello";`, sanjitguin's code *dereferences* the pointers without changing the *value of the pointers themselves*.

Comment: @unwind -Sorry i think the point was missed here, with assignment i meant *a[0]='s'*, etc.

Comment: @tangrs - i obviously did not mean by assignment that `a` and `b` are getting any values assigned, by assignment i meant the characters which the OP is trying to store in some garbage value.

Comment: @Acme Yes, but they (characters) are not assigned to the _pointer_ exactly.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare any variable it comes with whatever it had in memory previously where your application is running, and since pointers are essentially numbers, whatever number it had referenced to some random memory address.

Then, when setting `a[i]`, the compiler interprets that as you want to step `sizeof(a)` bytes forward, thus, `a[i]` is equal to the address `(a + i*1)` (1 because `char`s use one byte).

Finally, C-strings need to be NULL terminated (`\0`, also known as sentinel), and methods like `strlen` go over the length of the string until hitting the sentinel, most likely, your memory had a stray `0` somewhere that caused `strlen` to stop.

Answer (score 1):

Allocate some memory and terminate the strings then it will work better

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>


    void main(){
            char *a=malloc(10);
            char *b=malloc(10);
            if(a){
                    a[0]='s';
                    a[1]='a';
                    a[2]='n';
                    a[3]='j';
                    a[4]='i';
                    a[5]='t';
                    a[6]=(char)0;   
                    printf("length of a %d\n", (int)strlen(a));
            }else{
                    printf("Failed to allocate 10 bytes\n" );
            }
            if(b){
                    b[0]='s';
                    b[1]='a';
                    b[2]='n';
                    b[3]='j';
                    b[4]='i';
                    b[5]='t';
                    b[6]='g';
                    b[7]=(char)0;   

                    printf("length of b %d\n", (int)strlen(b));
            }else{
                    printf("Failed to allocate 10 bytes\n" );
            }
            free(a);
            free(b);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Undefined behavior. That's all.

You're using an uninitialized pointer. After that, all bets are off as to what will happen.

Of course, we can attempt to explain why your particular implementation acts in a certain way but it'd be quite pointless outside of novelty.

Answer (score 0):

The indexing operator is *de-referencing* the pointers `a` and `b`, but you never initialized those pointers to point at valid memory. Writing to un-initialized memory triggers undefined behavior.

You are simply "lucky" (or unlucky, it depends on your viewpoint) that the program doesn't crash, that the pointer values are such that you succeed in writing at those locations.

Note that you never write the termination character (`'\0'`) to either string, but still get the "right" value from `strlen()`; this implies that `a` and `b` both point at memory that happens to be full of zeros. More luck.

This is a very broken program; that it manages to run "successfully" is because it's behavior is *undefined*, and undefined clearly includes "working as the programmer intended".

Answer (score 0):

`a` and `b` are both `char` pointers. First of all, you didn't initialise them and secondly didn't terminate them with `NULL`.

Comment: In case of char pointer, compiler needs to know where it should stop.